# sent SOL from Phantom Wallet to CLI created wallet with no success

Tags: command-line-interface, wallet, solana

i'm just getting started with sol following this tutorial https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/sol-mint-token.

I sent 0.1 sol from my phantom wallet to a wallet i created in CLI with no success. the transaction appears as finalized on solscan, but the wallet's balance is 0

transaction id:
https://solscan.io/tx/4NK1uVS9zR3VdQogBbG5KgUkXYxX2ZTiZnmjJBJcpmiFMhR52MV4sYneDAiq786U1z9GtSEDtrQT4sXg81ExZ9Ht

Any idea why is this happening ? Many thanks.

Comment: update. i was on the testnet not mainnet

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 4):

As you've pointed out, this is due to the different networks.  Mainnet and testnet are totally separate, so if you've transfered 0.1 SOL on mainnet, testnet will be unaffected.

Looking at the recipient account on testnet vs mainnet, we have:

```
$ solana config set --url mainnet-beta
Config File: /home/jon/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/jon/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed

$ solana balance B1ZrGsHn4tTT6M4m2zxBL1Fk2sSp8JZMbu4vrAkhJLLm
0.019995 SOL

$ solana config set --url testnet
Config File: /home/jon/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.testnet.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.testnet.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/jon/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed

$ solana balance B1ZrGsHn4tTT6M4m2zxBL1Fk2sSp8JZMbu4vrAkhJLLm
0 SOL
```

So the account has 0.019995 SOL on mainnet, and 0 on testnet.  If you want to get a balance to this account on testnet, you'll have to change your wallet's network to testnet and airdrop yourself some testnet SOL before doing the transfer.

Comment: be careful with this guy's shorthanded URL. I followed it and took several hours of just simple things with --url option to realize better have it as full url rather than a shorthand domain